# Correct Content-Type header for NMEA data?

Tags: http, http-headers, mime-types, nmea

I want to send a bunch of NMEA sentences to my server in an HTTP POST body, but I am confused with what the `Content-Type` should be.

I didn't find a standard IANA MIME type for NMEA (appart from the generic `text/plain`). Should I use a custom one (like `application/vnd.myvnd.nmea`) or is there an obscure *de facto* standard one?

Comment: Excellent question.  I think that the `Content-Type` header should contain the outermost container.  Since these are just text, you could use `text/plain`... but some other sort of content type may be more appropriate if it exists.  I think your idea of a vendor type is best.

Comment: Thanks. Please, make an answer with that explanation so I can select it as the correct one.

Comment: I'm not totally confident in my answer, which is why I left it as a comment.  I'll do one better... I'll start a bounty and perhaps someone can research it and confirm what I wrote is correct, or come up with a different answer that is more correct.

Answer (score 4):

Since you refer to text, I assume that by NMEA we mean either the text-based specification **NMEA-0183**, as per Wikipedia:

> NMEA 0183 is a combined electrical and data specification for communication between marine electronics such as echo sounder, sonars, anemometer, gyrocompass, autopilot, GPS receivers and many other types of instruments. It has been defined by, and is controlled by, the National Marine Electronics Association.

or else text messages derived from the newer NMEA standard, **NMEA-2000**, a binary frame-based protocol that is essentially a profile of the **CAN** (controller area network) bus protocol used in automobile networks.

The official NMEA-0183 specification stops at the RS422 serial lines over which the protocol was designed to run. Data encoding is specified as ASCII with the high bit not used. The principal publicly available reference source for NMEA-0183 is  [Eric Raymond's "NMEA REVEALED"](http://www.catb.org/gpsd/NMEA.html).

The official NMEA-2000 standard uses the device interconnection specification of the CAN bus.

There is a proprietary (uncommon) standard for moving NMEA data over IP networks, and there are also a set of non-proprietary protocols more commonly used for that purpose. These are documented in a series of blog posts by the author of KPLEX, one of the well-known NMEA-0183 multiplexing tools. Particularly useful is the post entitled ["NMEA-0183 over IP: The unwritten rules for programmers."](http://stripydog.blogspot.com/2015/03/nmea-0183-over-ip-unwritten-rules-for.html)

Signal-K is an open source project that wraps NMEA and other data types using IANA standard protocols for the web, using Json objects and also TCP streams with unofficial names like `signalk-tcp`. The SignalK specification is [here](http://signalk.org/specification/1.0.4/doc/).

Other well-known open source projects involving NMEA data include:

- The OpenChartPlotterNavigation home [here](https://opencpn.org/).
- The Kplex home [here](http://www.stripydog.com/kplex/index.html).
- The OpenSkipper home [here](http://openskipper.org/).
- The CANBoat wiki [here](https://github.com/canboat/canboat/wiki).

There is no IANA MIME type registered for NMEA-0183, NMEA-2000, or CAN Bus. I downloaded and searched the sourcecode for the linked projects, and found no NMEA-relevant MIME types defined in any of the referenced projects or links.

Therefore I think we can say with some confidence that there when it comes to NMEA data, there is not an **obscure *de facto* standard** for `Content-Type`.

Comment: Wow! That's a lot of information. You are correct in your first sentence. I see the "rule of thumb" with NEMEA is sending it in plain TCP/UDP packets, then. Or, if HTTP is involved, as part of other lower layer protocol (i.e. embedded in JSON, XML, ...)

Comment: @xOneca If you're sending NMEA over HTTP, there is still no reason to embed it in JSON or XML.  It's just fine as-is, and can even be streamed by web browsers.

Comment: I agree with you, @Brad. What I meant is a lot of applications use JSON when using HTTP/WebSockets.